# website using divi - wordpress working on google chrome but no safari

Tags: css, wordpress, google-chrome, safari

I have been working on a website using divi - wordpress and seems to work well on google chrome. The sad thing is that I opened safari and all the blocks and everything are moved or above each other and there's even some elements that you can't even see (like the contact form for example).

I'm very new with creating websites so I don't really know what could be creating this visual bug on safari. I tried to look some info on google and divi blogs etc but I haven't find any answer so far. Is there someone that has been in a similar situation before or that know about this kind of browser issues that could give me some advice?

Thank you so much for your time and your help !

here the website : http://231e47.com/accueil-cf/

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is with Autoptomize. When it tries to aggregate and minify Divi's js, it often creates issues. Deactivate Autoptimize, clear the cache, and that should help.

I'm also getting a couple other errors in the console you might want to look into here:
[Safari JavaScript console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGOUt.png)